# Changing foreign key reference of table

Tags: mysql, reference, alter-table, updating

How can I change my foreign key reference from one table to another?

I tried to update but the syntax is not semantically correct,

I tried to run this statement in order to perform my required operation,

```
Alter table tablename
Columnname foreign key 
References table( column_name) ;
```

Comment: A trip to the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key is a constraint, not a column that you add.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD CONSTRAINT (columnName) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES otherTable (columnName);
```

See the [`ALTER TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) documentation.

Comment: ??op would need to drop old fk first then add, and synatx is ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (columnName) REFERENCES otherTable (columnName);

Comment: you can have multiple foreign keys, you don't have to drop one to add another.

Comment: Indeed but that's not the question..